# Localizing iPad app changed my executable name

Tags: ipad, localization, executable

so I have an ipad app in the app store with an executable name like 'dutch.app'. Now I added an english localization to my app and when I build it now for distribution my executable is all of a sudden named 'english.app'. I can submit this just fine to the app store but I'm afraid users that update to the new version will have a problem with it since the executable name has changed.

The only place where english is mentioned is in the InfoPlist.strings where I specified the cfbundledisplayname. It looks like the english localization overrules the dutch one.

Will this cause a problem or will users with the old executable name have no problem running the new version?

Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The filename doesn't matter at all.